# How can I update all rows except the last one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my script:

```
try{

    $dbh_conn->beginTransaction();

    $user_id = $_POST['iuser_id'];
    $token   = hash('sha512', bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)).$user_id);

    $stm = $dbh_conn
    ->prepare("INSERT INTO resend_pass(user_id, token, date_time)
                SELECT ?, ?, unix_timestamp()
                FROM dual
                WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
                                         COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))),0)  as num_day,
                                         COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))),0) as num_hour,
                                         COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))),0) as num_1min
                                    FROM resend_pass
                                   WHERE user_id   = ?  
                                     AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                                  HAVING num_week > 11 OR num_day > 5 OR num_hour > 3 OR num_1min > 0 );");
    $stm->execute(array($user_id, $token, $user_id));

    // no row inserted (either there is lots of reuqests or duplicate token (this one has very low possibility))
    if ( !$stm->rowCount() ) { throw new Exception('something is wrong'); }

    $stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE resend_pass SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ? AND {all rows except the last one}");
    $stmt->execute($user_id);

    $dbh_conn->commit();

    /* sending $token for that email  here  */

    $_SESSION["TopMSG"] = "<div class='msg_success'>
                            ایمیل با موفقیت ارسال شد 
                            <span>
                            - جهت انتخاب رمز عبور جدید
                            </span>
                            </div>";
    header('location: ../login');
    exit;

} catch(Exception $e) {

    $dbh_conn->rollBack();

    $_SESSION["TopMSG"] = "<div class='msg_success'>$e</div>";
    header('location: ../login');
    exit;

}
```

Please focus on this line:

```
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE resend_pass SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ? AND {all rows except the last one}");
```

How can I tell it set all rows except the last one which is inserted just now?

Comment: Does the table have an auto_increment primary key column and does that `INSERT` action always result in one single row inserted?

Comment: tables have no concept of "last" what is the real criteria here?

Comment: If the ID you want to exclude is the autoincrement of the last row you inserted, you can use the MySQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() directly in your query e.g. `AND xxx != LAST_INSERT_ID()`. No need to use PHP to get it.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

You can get the last inserted ID and use that in your where clause.

```
$lastId = $dbh_conn->lastInsertId();
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE resend_pass SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ? AND [whatever column is used for resend_pass id] <> ?");
$stmt->execute(array($user_id, $lastId));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto-increment column in your table you can get the id of the last inserted row and add that to the WHERE clause of the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier to move the following statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE resend_pass SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ?");
```

Above the Insert one, so there is no need to change the new record. and also the AND condition is no longer required

Regards

Comment: that statement is not valid sql so I doubt that would work -- maybe you need to change the statement slightly?

Comment: Yes, it needed some rework, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you think of "last".  It might be the max date, it might be the min date, it might be max id, it might be min id.  In the example below I use min date_time field.  Replace the sub-query with what you need

```
 UPDATE resend_pass 
    SET active = 0 
  WHERE user_id = ? AND date_time <> 
   (select min(date_time) 
      from resend_pass
    where user_id = ?)
```

Comment: What about writing this query `UPDATE resend_pass SET active = 0 WHERE user_id = ?` before that `INSERT` statement ?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question well, then i think you can get the id of the last inserted row using your PDO Connection

```
$lastId = $dbh_conn->lastInsertId();
```

Then use the value of `$lastId` in the sql query.

Comment: This is exactly the same as @caius 's answer